# Getting "MongoDB error An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: unreachable network." Error when try to do mongoDB migrate with Prisma

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm developing App using NextJS with Prisma ORM and use MongoDB as the DB. I'm using a FREE and SHARED MongoDB cluster that is hosted in MongoDB Altas cloud. Also I added `0.0.0.0/0` to the network access tab so anyone can connect to the DB.

But when I try to run `npx prisma db push` command it gives following output

Environment variables loaded from .env

```
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database "test" at "cluster1.movcamf.mongodb.net"
Error: MongoDB error
An error occurred during DNS resolution: proto error: io error: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (os error 10051)
   0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate `from`
             at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:43
   1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:441
```

Comment: Problem is TRASH Norton Security -_-

Comment: I disabled the windows defender firewall and then change the network , it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I changed my DNS to Cloudflare, and it's working well. Here's how to do it:

1. Follow the instructions at https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setup/windows/
2. After following those instructions, open your command prompt and enter the following commands:

`ipconfig /release`
`ipconfig /renew`
`ipconfig /flushdns`

These commands will help ensure that your new DNS settings take effect.